# Does anyone know what this plant with stiff red and green leaves is?

Tags: identification, bromeliads

I have kept this alive for months, but don't know if it is indoors or outdoors

[image: bromeliad]

Answer (score 2):

The picture is a bit dark, but I think it is [Bromeliad](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/bromeliad/growing-bromeliad-plants.htm). See link for care instructions. The plant is suitable for indoor, and depending on your climate it might be an outdoor plant as well.